# Get column matching text in excel range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, contains

I have lots of columns with values.

I want one specific column (outside that range) to obtain the value from the cells that start with "country: ".

So for example, if that range holds a cell in (let's say) F1 that starts with "country: ", then A1 should ALSO have that value, and so on.

To be more precise, I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3khwX.jpg).

Thank you!

Comment: There are a few things unclear: (1) Is it possible that more than one column in the data range has a row starting with `country: `? (2) Is it possible that for a given row, no column has a row starting with `country: `? (3) I am assuming the formula shall apply row-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this

### Approach 1: using `FILTER()` and `SEARCH()`

```
=FILTER(G2:K2,NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("country: ",G2:K2))))
```

which returns a `#CALC!` error when there is no row containing "country: " and a `#SPILL!` error when more than one row contains "country: " (unless there is enough space to show the whole spill). See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXa2I.png)

### Approach 2: using `INDEX()`, `MATCH()` and `LEFT()`

```
=INDEX(G2:K2,MATCH(TRUE,LEFT(G2:K2,9)="country: ",0))
```

which returns a `#N/A` error when there is no row containing "country: " and a the first match when more than one row contains "country: ". See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cSQ0.png)

### Approach 3: `XLOOKUP()` and `LEFT()`

```
=XLOOKUP("country: ",LEFT(G2:K2,9),G2:K2)
```

which returns a `#N/A` error when there is no row containing "country: " and a the first match when more than one row contains "country: ". See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJXG.png)

### Approach 4: `CONCAT()`, `IF()` and `LEFT()`

```
=CONCAT(IF(LEFT(G2:K2,9)="country: ",G2:K2,""))
```

which returns an **empty string** when there is no row containing "country: " and **concatenates matches** when more than one row contains "country: ". See example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2pAz.png)

### Conclusion

There are many other ways of getting results for your problem. If you could specify whether there can be none or multiple matching columns in a given row, and also how you would like such a scenario to be handled, it would be possible to show you a more precise solution.

Answer (score -1):

i use excel in turkish, and the fucntion in cell F2 like this:

`=EĞERHATA(DOLAYLI(ADRES(HÜCRE("sat";F2);HÜCRE("süt";F2)+BÜYÜK(EĞERHATA((BUL("country";$G2:$P2)>0);0)*$G$1:$P$1;TOPLA.ÇARPIM(EĞERHATA((BUL("country";$G2:$P2)>0);0)*1))));"")`

and i use translator add-in an in english, it can be like that:

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CELL("row",F2),CELL("col",F2)+LARGE(IFERROR((FIND("country",$G2:$P2)>0),0)*$G$1:$P$1,SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((FIND("country",$G2:$P2)>0),0)*1)))),"")`
NOTE:
this fuction can work if u give number to cells G1 = 1 / H1 = 2 ....

like

[page picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T62P8.jpg)